# 2D pattern matching in a noisy dataset

Tags: algorithm, pattern-matching, cluster-analysis

I have a data set given by an RFID antenna on 2D x,y location of two people moving. One person is carrying 3 RFID tags while the other is carrying 4 tags. Both are moving along the y axis as below. Red and Cyan are the paths, two people are walking.

[image]

The location map on a x,y scale looks like below.

[image]

Ideally, Orange, Yellow, Blue and Gray lines (RFID x,y data points) should go on a positive horizontal line while the below Green, Dark blue and Sky blue lines should go on a negative horizontal line.

**Question**
Although the lines are not straight, a visual pattern is emerged which can cluster above zero lines together and below zero lines together. My question is what algorithm/method can be used to compare such patterns and cluster them together. (So ideally the answer should be, above 4 lines are in one cluster and below 3 lines are in another cluster.)

*It's difficult to think it as a linear movement always as people can walk in non linear ways. So best fit lines would not work. Any suggestion or shading of light is thankfully appreciated.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to look at methods for clustering time series (1d) or trajectories (2d).

The approach for both is pretty much the same. First, you want to find a suitable distance metric(dissimilarity measure), second, you decide for a suitable clustering algorithm.

**Possible Distance Metrics**

Here are some example distances you could use, with some short arguments for each:

- Euclidean Distance: Very basic
- Dynamic Time Wraping (DTW): Can account for shifts
- Longuest Common Subsequence (LCSS): Accounts for shifts and can handle outliers
- Edit distance with Real Penalty (EDP): Accounts for shifts and can handle outliers

More details can for example be found in [this paper](http://crpit.com/confpapers/CRPITV137Wang.pdf). An implementation of the distances can be found [here](https://github.com/maikol-solis/trajectory_distance).

**Possible Cluster Algorithms**

- [K-Means](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-means_clustering)
- [DBSCAN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBSCAN)
- [Single Linkage clustering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-linkage_clustering)

You can usually combine any distances metric with any distance based clustering algorithm.

**Opinion**

Looking at your data I would try DTW as a distance metric. If you expect two clusters then K-Means with k=2 should work. Otherwise you could try Single Linkage Clustering, which will give you something similar to the image below.

[image: DTW+SLC]

Comment: Thanks SaiBot for the very descriptive answer. Just feeling curious, if I don't know the possible number of clusters, can any of these clustering algo dynamically get the number of clusters? For example, practically I don't know how many clusters would be there although I have drawn only two clusters in the image.

Comment: For K-Means there are some methods to [estimate the parameter k for a dataset](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determining_the_number_of_clusters_in_a_data_set). In DBScan you dont have to set the number of clusters but you have other parameters that basically let clusters grow as long as there are sufficiently many similar objects in an area. Methods like Single Link Clustering or OPTICS have no parameters and can help you evaluate your dataset visually and dynamically decide a cutoff point in the dendogram. Overall a non-trivial topic probably unsuited for a comment :-)